# What is the name of the approach (practice) when several unrelated entities are returned at once in the response to a request

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, architectural-patterns, mobile

For example, for a mobile frontend, you need to get all the data for rendering at once. The interface is divided into blocks, in which there can be both blocks with a catalog (categories) and other types, for example, banners with additional information, and they are all mixed on one page. Each block has a position number.

Comment: This is, more or less, what the term DTO (Data Transfer Object) originally meant. See: https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html

Comment: If you use this technique, you are possibly doing it wrong. You are adding complexity, whole depriving yourself from the benefit of parallel requests. With HTTP 2, it's hard to see any benefit in it.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko the idea is to manage the interface from the backend. something similar to Server Driven UI

Comment: If your front end knows “I will need unrelated a, b, and c” then it makes sense to have an endpoint that can return multiple unrelated items so you have one request instead of three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often called **bundling data** (but I don't think this is really a standardized or canonical term).

IMHO this topic isn't really "interesting enough" to find useful singular publications about it, it is just one network optimization technique among others. But when you google for "bundling data for network requests", you will surely get some results, like

- [Pattern: Request Bundle](https://microservice-api-patterns.org/patterns/quality/dataTransferParsimony/RequestBundle)
- [Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)
- [Optimize network access](https://developer.android.com/training/connectivity/network-access-optimization)